# I need to Parse a tab separated text file, convert from hex to decimal, plot specific values, then calculate RMS value

Tags: perl, parsing, powershell

I haven't coded since around 1984 so feeling a little lost. I have spent the day reviewing this and other sites but at this point feel more lost than when I began. I need to automate parsing of a tab separated text file. The row of text I need information from will look like this:

```
I  24-Jan-14 06:56:53   44  CT_CCS           0   <I> (E 01 13 2C 08 64 00 00) Waterflow monitoring
```

The text (log) file will have various other entries that for my current purposes I am not interested in. I am only interested in rows with `44  CT_CCS` in them.

I need to convert some of the values from the parentheses `(E 01 13 2C 08 64 00 00)`, specifically in this case the parameters occupied by the values `08 64`, from hex to decimal. Then I need to plot these values (there will typically be several hundred lines such as this in a given 24 hour period) over time. Finally I need to calculate the RMS value of the plot.

I have been doing most of this manually by parsing the log file with tools on the system it comes from to only show these rows with `44  CT_CCS` in them, then exporting this to a tab separated text file, importing the text file to an excel spreadsheet, further extracting the values in the parentheses into a new column and converting them to decimal, then plotting them with a pivot table. The RMS calculation is a new step I need to incorporate.

Since I need to do this for about 43 systems at the moment and there will be an ongoing need to do this I would like to automate this as much as possible. Either Perl or PowerShell were what I was thinking of attempting this in. Any thoughts or advice would be greatly appreciated.

So TheMadTechnician wrote the following code to help me with this:

Get-Content D:\Data\Temp\GIM_63_Project\Parsing_Script*.txt | Where{$_ -match "(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\s(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\sCT_CCS\s44\s((.*?))"}|%{
    $Record= New-Object -TypeName PSObject
    $Record | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Date" -Value ([datetime]::ParseExact($Matches[1],"yyyy-MM-dd",$null).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
    $Record | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "TimeStamp" -Value ([datetime]::ParseExact($Matches[2],"HH:mm:ss",$null).ToString("HH:mm:ss"))
    $Record | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Data" -Value ($Matches[3].split(" ")[4..5] -join ""|%{[Convert]::ToInt32($_,16)})
    $Record
} | Export-CSV D:\Data\Temp\GIM_63_Project\Parsing_Script\step1.csv -NoTypeInformation

This works very well to parse the data. What I have found is that there are outliers in my data that I need to eliminate. Any increase of more than 1000 between iterations in the value that results from the following line need to be eliminated: $Record | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Data" -Value ($Matches[3].split(" ")[4..5] -join ""|%{[Convert]::ToInt32($_,16)}).

I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: Currently, your question is a bit too broad for Stack Overflow. If you edit it to be more narrowly focused, you will probably get better responses. For example, "How can I convert the nth field in a tab-separated file from hex to decimal using Perl?" would be a better question. You've already broken your problem down into large pieces; now you simply need to solve each one.

Comment: Could you mark TABs in your sample line using `\t`?  I am under impression that the line contains spaces and TABs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest I do not know about the plotting and RMS bit, but the rest is really easy in PowerShell.

You'll need the Get-Content cmdlet, a Regular Expression match, use of a ForEach loop, creating PSCustomObjects, and the [Convert]::ToInt32() method.

```
Get-Content C:\Path\To\File.csv|Where{$_ -match "(\d{2}-...-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) 44 CT_CCS.*?\((.*?)\)"}|%{[pscustomobject][ordered]@{
    TimeStamp=[datetime]::ParseExact($Matches[1],"dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss",$null)
    Data=$Matches[2].split(" ")[4..5] -join ""|%{[Convert]::ToInt32($_,16)}
}}
```

That will output an array of custom objects with 2 properties (TimeStamp and Data) that are an actual DateTime object parsed from the date and time string listed, and the decimal values of the 5th, 6th, 7th, and 8th hex bytes (all mashed together, though I don't know if you want that or want them added, or what) within the parenthesis of any line in the file specified that has the "44 CT_CCS" string in it followed by something in parenthesis. Making up some random fake data (the third listed was your exact sample line) in a file output the following for me:

```
TimeStamp                                         Data
---------                                         ----
1/24/2014 6:56:53 AM                              4667
1/24/2014 7:12:04 AM                              43284
1/24/2014 7:31:59 AM                              2148
```

You could pipe that to a CSV file by adding `| Export-CSV C:\Path\To\NewFile.csv -NoTypeInformation` after the last `}` in that code.

As I said, I really don't know anything about the plotting or RMS bit but this at least gets you pairs of numbers that you could plot and convert. Perhaps somebody else could assist with the rest of that.

As for the Ones, Tens, Hundreds, and Thousands... `$Matches[2].Split(" ")` takes everything in the () from that line, and creates an array from it. I pipe that to a `ForEach` loop (alias `%` used) that performs `[Convert]::ToInt32($_,16)` on each hex number pair specified. I'm specifying records `[4..7]` which are the 5th through 8th number pairs. In your example that would be 08, 64, 00, and 00. If you want more just change the `[4..7]` to whatever you want to include. If you want to break it down into different columns you can add more lines. Such as:

```
    Data=($Matches[2].split(" ")[4..7]|%{[Convert]::ToInt32($_,16)}) -join ""
```

could become:

```
    Ones=$Matches[2].split(" ")[4]|%{[Convert]::ToInt32($_,16)}
    Tens=$Matches[2].split(" ")[5]|%{[Convert]::ToInt32($_,16)}
    Hundreds=$Matches[2].split(" ")[6]|%{[Convert]::ToInt32($_,16)}
    Thousands=$Matches[2].split(" ")[7]|%{[Convert]::ToInt32($_,16)}
```

That would output (using my same fake data):

```
TimeStamp            Ones                Tens                Hundreds            Thousands          
---------            ----                ----                --------            ---------          
1/24/2014 6:56:53 AM 18                  59                  0                   0                  
1/24/2014 7:12:04 AM 169                 20                  0                   0                  
1/24/2014 7:31:59 AM 8                   100                 0                   0
```

**Edit:** Ok, use the code with `TimeStamp=` and `Data=` up above. It now grabs the 0864 and converts that to dec like you want it to.

**Edit w/ your code:** I copied and pasted your code into my PowerShell and modified it a little (missing some `\` characters). I ran it and it ran ok, but I realized that having date and time separate would probably be a good thing so I split those out. I ran it against a text file named SomeFile.txt with these 3 lines:

```
I 24-Jan-14 06:56:53 44 CT_CCS 0 (E 01 13 2C 12 3B 00 00) Waterflow monitoring  
I 24-Jan-14 07:12:04 44 CT_CCS 0 (E 01 13 2C A9 14 00 00) Waterflow monitoring  
I 24-Jan-14 07:31:59 44 CT_CCS 0 (E 01 13 2C 08 64 00 00) Waterflow monitoring
```

It output a CSV containing this:

```
"Date","TimeStamp","Data"  
"01/24/2014","06:56:53","4667"  
"01/24/2014","07:12:04","43284"  
"01/24/2014","07:31:59","2148"
```

This is the code I ran to do that:

```
Get-Content D:\Data\Temp\GIM_63_Project\Parsing_Script\*.txt | Where{$_ -match "(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\s(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\sCT_CCS\s44\s(\(.*?\))"}|%{
    [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
        Date=[datetime]::ParseExact($Matches[1],"yyyy-MM-dd",$null).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
        TimeStamp=[datetime]::ParseExact($Matches[2],"HH:mm:ss",$null).ToString("HH:mm:ss") 
        Data=$Matches[3].split(" ")[4..5] -join ""|%{[Convert]::ToInt32($_,16)}
    }
} | Export-CSV D:\Data\Temp\GIM_63_Project\Parsing_Script\step1.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: TheMadTechnician - thanx very much for your response. This is very helpful!! I can import this output to an excel spreadsheet to plot and calculate the RMS value. I will play with what you posted to see if I can get it to do precisely what I want. The A & B values equate to the; ones, tens, hundreds, thousands, places to the left of the decimal point so I don't need them in separate columns. Thanx again!!

Comment: Now that I think about it further I need A to be the time (which is indicated near the beginning of each string, and B to be the decimal value of the 4 hexadecimal digits from within the parentheses as previously indicated. That way the decimal value is correlated to a time and can then be plotted in subsequent steps.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. I'll update my answer and let you know when it's right.

Comment: So wait, in the parenthesis you are interested in the `08 64 00 00` then right? You said ones, tens, hundreds, thousands, but only listed two bytes.

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer. It may prove more useful to your needs now.

Comment: In the parentheses I am interested only in the positions occupied in my example by 08 64, not the subsequent zeros. 08 64 equates to 0864 (in hex) liters per hour or converted to decimal 2148 liters per hour. I need to output (plot) the time and liters per hour in decimal for each entry in the log of the 44 CT_CCS string.

Comment: By using the following:                                                                                                                                        select-string -path D:\Data\Temp\GIM_63_Project\Parsing_Script\*.txt -pattern "CT_CCS(.)*44" -allmatches> D:\Data\Temp\GIM_63_Project\Parsing_Script\step1.txt                 I have found that I can get just the strings I am interested in.
Now I just need to output the time, and the 5th & 6th pairs of digits, convert them from hex to decimal, and output them

Comment: Ok, re-updated the answer. It should give you what you want. Creating a plot can be done in PowerShell with Windows.Forms and Root-Mean-Square could be done too if desired.

Comment: The limit to the number of characters in a response is making it difficult to be concise in my response to you, sorry...

Comment: Ok, thank you again very much!! The new output look right. I will give it a try. Thanks again!

Comment: this is what I have:                                                     Get-Content D:\Data\Temp\GIM_63_Project\Parsing_Script\*.txt | Where{$_ -match "(\d{2}-...-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) 44 CT_CCS.*?\((.*?)\)"}|%{[pscustomobject][ordered]@{
    TimeStamp=[datetime]::ParseExact($Matches[1],"dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss",$null)
    Data=$Matches[2].split(" ")[4..5] -join ""|%{[Convert]::ToInt32($_,16)}
}} | Export-CSV D:\Data\Temp\GIM_63_Project\Parsing_Script\step1.csv

Comment: It creates the .csv file but it is empty...

Comment: Still getting an empty csv file... Can I send you the log file I am using? It is just over 8 MB. Is there a way to do that with-in the forum tools or will email work?

Comment: There is no way to do that via StackOverflow that I know of. I'm not sure what my email size limit is, but you may want to send me half of that file (5mb is a common limit for external addresses in my experience). Not posting my email in plain text to be scraped by a web bot, so paste this into PowerShell: `("6d6174746865772e65726e737440636f6d7075636f6d2e636f6d" -split "(..)"|%{if($_ -match "(..)"){[CHAR][BYTE]([CONVERT]::ToInt16($_,16))}}) -join ""`

Comment: ok, sent you the log. Thanks again!